# DRF Serializer - OrderDict instead of JSON

Tags: django, django-serializer

I am new to Django1.9,

models.py:-

```
class MyUser(models.Model):

    UserId = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    UserFirstName = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    UserLastName = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    UserEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=1000,blank=False,null=True)
    UserContactNumber = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    UserPassword = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    IsActive = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Role = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=1000), blank=True,null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering =('IsActive',)
```

serializers.py:-

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

Shell output :-

```
>>> from projectmanagement.serializers import MyUserSerializer
>>> users = MyUser.objects.all()
>>> users
[<MyUser: MyUser object>, <MyUser: MyUser object>]
>>> serializer = MyUserSerializer(users,many=True)
>>> serializer
MyUserSerializer([<MyUser: MyUser object>, <MyUser: MyUser object>], many=True):
    UserId = UUIDField(label='UserId', read_only=True)
    UserFirstName = CharField(label='UserFirstName', max_length=1000)
    UserLastName = CharField(label='UserLastName', max_length=1000)
    UserEmail = EmailField(allow_null=True, label='UserEmail', max_length=1000, required=False)
    UserContactNumber = CharField(label='UserContactNumber', max_length=1000)
    UserPassword = CharField(label='UserPassword', max_length=1000)
    IsActive = BooleanField(label='IsActive', required=False)
    Role = ListField(allow_null=True, child=CharField(label='Role', max_length=1000), required=False)
>>> serializer.data
[OrderedDict([('UserId', 'fd5df8d3-a578-4fe7-95ea-172ad2399ff8'), ('UserFirstName', u''), ('UserLastName', u''), ('UserEmail', None), ('UserContactNumber', u''), ('UserPassword', u''), ('IsActive', False), ('Role', None)]), OrderedDict([('UserId', '8301e1b6-a031-443f-957a-df98025e5e9f'), ('UserFirstName', u'Piyush'), ('UserLastName', u'Wanare'), ('UserEmail', u'piyush@uniserved.com'), ('UserContactNumber', u'992053268236'), ('UserPassword', u'Piyush@1234'), ('IsActive', True), ('Role', [u'Vendor Cordinator'])])]
```

Why I am not getting JSON data instead of OrderedDict?
How can I get data in JSON format?

Answer (score 11):

I guess you are using Django REST Framework?

It's not well-documented in the DRF's `Tutorial` or `API Guide`. But example is actually given in **`Tutorial 1: Serialization`** for serializing a queryset:

```
serializer = SnippetSerializer(Snippet.objects.all(), many=True)
serializer.data
# [OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('title', u''), ('code', u'foo = "bar"\n'), ('linenos', False), ('language', 'python'), ('style', 'friendly')]), OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('title', u''), ('code', u'print "hello, world"\n'), ('linenos', False), ('language', 'python'), ('style', 'friendly')]), OrderedDict([('id', 3), ('title', u''), ('code', u'print "hello, world"'), ('linenos', False), ('language', 'python'), ('style', 'friendly')])]
```

To get data in JSON format:

```
import json
serializer = MyUserSerializer(users,many=True)
json.dumps(serializer.data)
```

Comment: This should be accepted. And thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to serialize the response as a JSON first.

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

class LazyEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, YourCustomType):
            return force_text(obj)
        return super(LazyEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json

And if your end goal is to do it as an HTTP response, you can also use this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Also try to upgrade to Django 1.11 as 1.9 is no longer supported. Check here on how to upgrade: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/upgrade-version/

Comment: Where should I fit it in my serializer?

Comment: Quick question though, are you using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) as well?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use serializers :

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", MyUser.objects.all())
```

The doc is here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/

But please upgrade to 1.11, 1.9 is insecure version

With DRF, `serializers.ModelSerializer` do the job by default, so it's a good idea to install it : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Answer (score 0):

Simply just put this code in setting.py file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
]}
```

And get your JSON data by

```
serializer.data
```